# Garage conducts work without my consent

Tags: engine, turbocharger

So my car was sent to a car garage to have a recon engine and turbo diagnosed for our warranty.
The examiner went to access and my claim has been cancelled and warranty void as the garage have already completed the works put new engine and turbo in without my consent or the go ahead of the warranty company.
How do I legally stand I need my car I’m not prepared to pay £7.5k when the warranty was going to cover most of this. I’m worried

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure how it works in the UK from a legal standpoint. I take it the garage which did the work was not one which was authorized to do the work under warranty and that's the reason the warranty was canceled? What is the year/make/model of your vehicle?

Comment: The make is a Land Rover discovery 2015 so the garage were ment to wait for the examiner to say yay/ nay to the cover of the claim he got there the engine was awash changed and the old one in a pile of others with parts missing

Comment: I'm not a lawyer and I'm from the States, so take this with a grain of salt ... I think I'd hire legal counsel. From what you've stated, it seems as though the shop screwed up. You *know* they aren't going to suck up a £7.5k bill on their own. You're going to have to press them. To me it seems, since they voided your warranty, they should be paying for the new engine/turbo for your Discovery. That's just my opinion. At the very least, you're going to want to talk to an attorney and see what they think.

Comment: What warranty? The manufacturer's warranty on a new car, or a used-car dealer's "warranty" (usually an insurance policy)? And "my car was sent to a car garage..." – who by? This might be a better question on [SE Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) with much more detail added. AFAIK in UK the garage is not allowed to hold your car to ransom against payment (though they might try).